# Ajax returning whole HTML document on laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm having this trouble on ajax request.

When running on localhost I have no problem, when browsing from any pc on the network, I get the whole html page on data.

My code looks like this:

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{{url("remates/hayRemateActivo")}}',
    async:false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.dir("valor:"+data+".");
        if (data == 1){
            location.reload();
        }
    },
    error(e){
        document.write(e.responseText);
    }
})
```

My route looks like this:

```
Route::post('remates/hayRemateActivo','RemateController@hayRemateActivo');
```

My controller looks like this:

```
public function hayRemateActivo(){
    $remates = Remate::where('estado',1)
    ->first();
    #dd(var_dump($remates));

    // load the view and pass the nerds
    return (string)(gettype($remates) != 'NULL');
}
```

On localhost on data I get "" when the condition is not met, and "1" when the condition is met, as I expect.

But when I browse from any other pc on the network, on data I get a whole HTML document which replicates the page where I call it from, what's the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AJAX is doing exactly what it is supped to do - returning everything the remote script echos.

Comment: is the `dd` part still in the code when you're testing?

Comment: nope, was about to make it clear that dd was used while debugging said problem

Comment: I am not an expert on laravel but could it be that u are using relative paths in routes? as in "remates/hayRemateActivo" instead of "/remates/hayRemateActivo". ignore me if this is how laravel supposed to work

Comment: No, the url that I'm getting on the ajax is correct

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out the problem, the route I was calling went through a middleware that required an user to be logged in.

Putting the route outside the middleware group solved the problem.